# PHP select data using pdo get into array and use the data

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, authentication

I have a login, where i need to pull data given the email, i do this with a select and pdo. But it isn't working.

I get the password and email given from a form. Then i check if there not empty, then i want to get the password from the database to check it with the given password. If this is good, then i give the account id and username in a session.
If it was not good, i set the header and give a error message

```html
try {
    $connect = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostnaam; dbname=$databasenaam", $gebruikersnaam, $wachtwoord);

    $connect->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    }
catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    echo "Connectie mislukt: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
```

```html
<?php



ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('log_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL); mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
ob_start();


if(isset($_REQUEST['password']))
{

    require 'connect.php';  
    $password = $_REQUEST['password'];
    $mail = $_REQUEST['email'];

    if(empty($mail) || empty($password)){
        header('location: ../login.php?error=empty');
        exit();
    }
    else{
        
        
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM account WHERE email = $mail";
        $result = $connect->prepare($sql); 
        $result->execute();
        $row = $result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

               $passwordCheck = password_verify($password_hashed, $pdo['wachtwoord']);
                if($passwordCheck == false ){

                    header("Location: ../login.php?error=passwordWrong");
                    exit();
                }
                else if($passwordCheck == true){
                    session_start();
                    $_SESSION['userId'] = $row['account_id'];
                    $_SESSION['username'] = $row['gebruikersnaam'];
                    header("Location: ../index.php?login=succes");
                    exit();
                }
            
else{
                
                header("Location: login.php?error=noUser");
                exit();
            }
    }
}
else{
    header("Location: ../login.php?error=fail");
    exit();
}
```

Comment: Can we see the definition for the $connect variable?

Comment: try {
    $connect = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostnaam; dbname=$databasenaam", $gebruikersnaam, $wachtwoord);

    $connect->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    }
catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    echo "Connectie mislukt: " . $e->getMessage();
    }

Comment: @RussJ it is in the question now, i left out the vars because it contains sensitive data